# Is it possible to declare a recursive using alias directive in C#?

Tags: c#, using-directives, type-alias

This example gives a "The type or namespace name 'MyType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
using MyType = System.Func<System.Int32, System.Tuple<System.Int32, MyType>>;
```

Is it at all possible to declare a recursive type like this?

Comment: I normally don't ask this but... why?

Comment: I'm just playing around trying to declare a minimal encoding of the actor model in C#, so I though I'd use a recursive function alias to model the behavior changing nature of actors.

Comment: I haven't thought about it for more than a few minutes but my suspicion is you probably want some kind of generic factory, e.g. a `CreateActor<T>` that returns an object with a `public Func<int, Tuple<int, T>> action;` but I don't have anything concrete off the top of my head.

Comment: Yup, I think I got to the same conclusion formulating the tuple instantiation below. Had to inject a lazy evaluation step to break the recursion, and I guess the factory type counts as such.

Comment: For the curious, I ended up just using an interface instead:     public interface Behavior { Behavior Recieve(Message message, Action<Actor, Message> activator); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it is possible. The right-hand side of your `using` statement needs to resolve to a real type before you can assign an alias to it. In your case, in order to resolve the right-hande side, the compiler must fully define the allias... which requires it to resolve the right-hand side. This recursive problem has no ending, so the compiler is clearly not going to bother.

To make the problem here more clear: lets assume the compiler managed to compile your alias, and I did this:

```
MyType mytype = x => Tuple<int, MyType>.Create(x, ???);
```

What could I possible put in the body of the function to define the return value? Eventually I need to have a constructable type somewhere to return.

Comment: MyType myType = x => Tuple<int, MyType>.Create(x+1, (y) => myType(y+x).Item2);

Comment: But I think you are correct, this approach will result in more headache than results...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about a using directive (at the top of a file) and MyType exists, yes, it is possible.  For instance, this is perfectly legal:

```
using System;
using String = System.Func<System.String>;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String myString = () => "Foo";
            // myString is now a function returning the string "Foo".  Yikes.
        }
    }
}
```

That said, it would never pass a code review by me.  Talk about confusing.

Comment: I don't think what he wants is possible: replace "String" with "Foo" and you have a function that returned a function that returned a function that returned a function...

Comment: The string example gives "The type or namespace name 'String' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield of course the right hand side has to resolve to a type.  My point is that the above works.

Comment: But the above, which works, is not what the OP is asking (I don't think).

Comment: It works with MyType as long as you dont use it in the same file where MyType is defined.

Comment: Michael is correct. The type in your example is not recursive, just shadowing the System.String type.

Comment: @ChrisShain that's true, and your example is absolutely correct, but I think the point of the original question is that MyType is *not* defined *anywhere* except in this `using` statement.